# Вертикальный и горизонтальный слайдинг экранов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Наткнулся на сайт где мне понравилась реализация слайдинга контента, при вертикальном скролле листаются страницы/блоки, внизу слева в виде человечков ссылки которые перелистывают горизонтально и затем когда листаешь вертикально - уже другой контент, как или с помощью чего такое можно реализовать ?

http://jenslehmann.com/#/ambassador

Comment: фулпейдже как обычно